# In Discrete Mathematics, is there a difference between $(\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ and $\neg (P \wedge Q)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

I am wondering, in discrete mathematics, whether there is a difference between 
$(\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ and $\neg (P \wedge Q)$.

My query comes from a practice problem in a book:

> Either John and Bill are both telling the truth, or neither of them is.

Any my solution above corresponds to $P ::=$ John is telling the truth, $Q ::=$ Bill is telling the truth.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, these two expressions are different (work out the truth-table and you will see) ... but I don't quite understand the connection of these expressions to your exercise .. can you please explain why you are looking at these two expressions in relation to that practice problem?

Comment: @Bram28 Well, that is just converting the English sentence into logic and connectives. I took the English sentence, and re-wrote it in terms of $P$ and $Q$, using the appropriate connectives. Thanks. But the fact they are different is all I need. I didn't think to work the Truth Table.

Comment: Well .... you didn't do the symbolization correctly ... OK, just take the part that they are both telling the truth. How would you symbolize that?

Comment: @Bram28 That is not my complete answer. My complete answer is: $(P ∧ Q) ∨ (\neg P ∧ \neg Q)$

Comment: OK, that looks good ... but there is no $\neg (P \land Q)$ in there ... so why are you asking about $\neg (P \land Q)$ in your original question?  Were you maybe thinking of writing it as $(P \land Q) \lor \neg (P \land Q)$?

Comment: @Bram28 I wasn't thinking properly when I wrote $\neg (P \wedge Q)$. I realize my mistake now.

Comment: Cool .. sometimes all it takes is just talking through your own thought process :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither John nor Bill telling the truth is:

$$\neg P \land \neg Q$$

or, equivalently:

$$\neg (P \lor Q)$$

But that is not the same as:

$$\neg (P \land Q)$$

because that is merely saying that it is not true that they are both telling the truth (i.e. that they are not both telling the truth)... which is compatible with one of the lying, but the other one still telling the truth.

In short: 'both not'  is not the same as 'not both'

Answer (score 1):

Try this for yourself:

Suppose $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. Then:

- Is $(\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ true or false?
- Is $\neg(P\wedge Q)$ true or false?

Answer (score 0):

These two statements does not have the same truth value as
By Demorgan's law, $ \neg(p \wedge q) = \neg p \vee \neg q$.

Here,
John and Bill are both telling the truth corresponds to $p \wedge q$.

The negation of the statement is either John is not telling the truth or Bill is not telling the truth($\neg p \vee \neg q$).

It is not the same as neither of them is telling the truth($\neg p \vee \neg q$).